# Multiple invisible google recaptcha on the same page

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I use the invisible google recaptcha v.3
On the same page i have 3 different forms.

Before the submit button of the forms I've added a div

```
<div class="g-recaptcha-contact" data-sitekey="XXXXXXX" id="RecaptchaField1"></div>
<div class="g-recaptcha-contact" data-sitekey="XXXXXXX" id="RecaptchaField2"></div>
<div class="g-recaptcha-contact" data-sitekey="XXXXXXX" id="RecaptchaField3"></div>
```

On the head i include

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=CaptchaCallback&render=explicit"></script>
```

and also added this piece of code to render the recaptcha

```
    var CaptchaCallback = function() {
    var widgetId1;
    var widgetId2;
    var widgetId3;
    widgetId1 = grecaptcha.render('RecaptchaField1', {'sitekey' : 'XXXXXX', 'callback' : correctCaptcha_quote});
    widgetId2 = grecaptcha.render('RecaptchaField2', {'sitekey' : 'XXXXXX', 'callback' : correctCaptcha_contact});
widgetId3 = grecaptcha.render('RecaptchaField3', {'sitekey' : 'XXXXXX', 'callback' : correctCaptcha_reg});
};
```

With this code i have 3 recaptchas with checkbox, not invisible. 
If i add parameter 'size': 'invisible' then only one of the 3 recaptchas is rendered and loaded, the first that is placed in code.

Comment: Can you please clarify what's the question? And why you need 3 re-captchas?

Comment: I have 3 different forms on the same page and i want to have recaptcha in all of them. The issue is that the recaptcha shows and works only in one of them

Comment: Re-captcha is related to Session on server. If you call 3 times re-captcha, then server value will change. Use single re-captcha.

Comment: Call your CaptCallBack 3 times with different names